# Need visa for new born baby parents are tier 2 visa b

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, dependent-visa, nhs

Parents are tier2 visa, pregnancy due date is may 8th 2024 and we have plan to leave UK end of July 2024. Parents’ tier2 visa will finish August 2024.

So will new born baby need visa and NHS fee?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a child while you’re in the UK, they do not automatically become a British citizen.

If your baby is born in the UK then they can remain in the UK without applying for a visa. However, if you need to travel outside the UK your baby will require a passport or travel document and they will also need a dependant visa to re-enter the UK. Your child will also not be covered for free hospital treatment after the age of 3 months if they have not paid the immigration healthcare surcharge as part of a visa application.

The form you fill in depends on whether your child is [inside or outside the UK.](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/your-partner-and-children)

You’ll need to provide a full UK birth certificate for each child, showing the names of both parents.